# Set up dnsmasq as a DHCP Proxy for UEFI HTTP(S) boot

Tags: pxe-boot, dnsmasq, uefi

Can I set up dnsmasq as a DHCP Proxy for UEFI HTTP(S) boot?

It appears hard to impossible, as dnsmasq only seems to support being a proxy for the older TFTP-based PXE Boot, and I don't want to send these options.

It looks as if it would be relatively straightforward to send the options I want using manual configuration, if dnsmasq was my network's DHCP server, as in that case you can more or less specify any options to send, based on any conditions, along with the address lease. But that is not what I want. I want a DHCP proxy (which as per the UEFI spec only sends the additional options required to locate the network boot file, relying on some other DHCP server on the network to provide the IP address lease). However, as mentioned above, when dnsmasq is in proxy mode it seems it will only send PXE Boot options, and has no support for the newer HTTP(S) Boot options.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely would not have got there without the two answers from other sites in the references below, but this is a working config which is letting OVMF HTTP Boot discover a URL and boot from it successfully:

```
# Disable DNS server
port=0

# Run as PXE Boot proxy
dhcp-range=192.168.1.0,proxy

# Trigger PXE Boot support on HTTP Boot client request
dhcp-pxe-vendor=HTTPClient

# Set triggering tag if correct arch is present in option 60
dhcp-match=set:arch_x64,option:client-arch,16

# Make PXE Boot support believe it has something to send...
pxe-service=tag:arch_x64,x86-64_EFI,"Network Boot"

# Specify bootfile-name option via PXE Boot setting
dhcp-boot=tag:arch_x64,http://192.168.1.234:8080/slitaz-rolling-core64.iso

# Force required vendor class in the response, even if not requested
dhcp-option-force=tag:arch_x64,option:vendor-class,HTTPClient
```

By the way when testing this, the following command line may be useful to start dnsmasq directly and see the log output:

```
sudo dnsmasq --no-daemon -C dnsmasq.conf --log-dhcp --log-debug
```

References:
[1] https://www.mail-archive.com/dnsmasq-discuss@lists.thekelleys.org.uk/msg16278.html
[2] https://github.com/ipxe/ipxe/discussions/569#discussioncomment-1994062